# Is my POST request correct? Spotify client_credential

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, spotify

I try to get a token from Spotify with Client Credentials Flow. I get in answer status 400 and this error : "invalid_client". I cannot understand where is my mistake.

```
let oAuthOptions = {
            url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(CLIENT_ID+':'+CLIENT_SECRET)
            },
            body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
            json : true
        };


        $.post(oAuthOptions['url'],oAuthOptions,function() {
            console.log('get answer');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The invalid_client error occurs when you are sending a bad Authorization header (not bad, maybe a bad client_id?)

Recheck your client_id and client_secret (And if they are properly in base64)
It should work.

Comment: I already checked it twice. I made an encoded string (base64) with client_Id and client_Server on Objective-C and they are similar. (On objective-c everything works).